# How to save session data without overloading database

Tags: mysql, django

I have a flashcard app database that will record user progress as they quiz themselves. Users will be answering questions with yes/no/maybe at a rate of about 5-10 seconds per response. The problem is that some users will continue this question/answer session for long periods of time and I don't want them to lose their progress if something distracts them and they close the app halfway through the study session.

One one hand, I could have each question send a request to the database to update user progress every time a user answers a question. On the other hand, I could have all of the progress saved somewhere on the client side (cookies?) and then update the database once at the end of the session. My fear is that the first option is not scalable if thousands of users use the site simultaneously. However, with the second option, I'm sure that progress will be lost if a user closes the session unexpectedly.

What is the best way to continuously save user progress without overloading the database?

Comment: You will never overload a well structured database base with 1 query per 5-10 seconds. 1000 users per 5-10 seconds also won't make a difference either. Ensure you are saving/updating results with a primary/secondary key.

Comment: I must be underestimating the power of mysql databases. Thank you for your contribution.